# Multiple substring extraction using sed

Tags: regex, sed, substring

I've got an xml file like:

```
<http:website/CODE1> <http:website/CODE2> <http:website/CODE3>
```

Where:

CODE1 is a code defined by 2 letters 2 numbers and 2 letters: AA11BB

CODE2 is a word: east or west

CODE3 is a floating number

I need to extract this codes filtering out the xml code. I need to use sed.
I thought something like (only to extract the first CODE):

```
sed 's/[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{2\}[A-Z]\{2\}!//g
```

In order to replace everything that doesn't match with the first RegEx with an empty space. The RegEx is right, but if I use the "negation" symbol than it doesn't work? What's wrong?
Furthermore, how can I apply multiple substitution to the same line?

Comment: you apply multiple substitutions to a line by chaining them together, i.e. `sed 's/a/b/;s/b/c/g;/s/x/y/' file`. It is also possible to put all of your actions into a file, one per line makes it easier to read, and then call it like `sed -f mySedScript.sed file`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint - since you seem to want to solve it yourself :)

```
sed 's/AAA\(.*\)BBB\(.*\)CCC/\1--\2 /'
```

Will look for something like

```
AAAsomethingBBBanotherCCC
```

and change it into

```
something--another
```

the `\(\)` is used to select a part, and the `\1` and `\2` are used to retrieve parts

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "
  /east/ s/.*\([A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]\)>.*\(east\).*\/\([0-9.,]\{1,\}\)>.*/\1 \2 \3/p
  /west/ s/.*\([A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]\)>.*\(west\).*\/\([0-9.,]\{1,\}\)>.*/\1 \2 \3/p
  " YourFile
```

Assuming there is only 1 triplet per line (if not, result could be a mix of the values on the line and 1 triplet to the output)

Included also the floating number using . ou , as separator (depend on environment)

Answer (score 0):

If your input text matches your example, 3 tags on one line, separated by spaces, with the target text between the final `/` and the closing `>` of each, then will work:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*\/\([^>]*\)>/\1/g' filename
```